# How to deal with helpful edits to very old questions by established users?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, old-questions

While browsing through the edit review queue, I stumbled across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8102263) to a 2 year old question, which I think improved the question a lot.
However, since the question is so old, I am not sure if I should accept the edit, and I feel kind of queasy about the whole thing.

I am not sure if things like the age of the question, or the rep levels of the OP and the editor should matter when reviewing a suggested edit to a question, and I was wondering if there is an established guideline to this?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** The edit in question has now been approved by others.

Comment: The [necroposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Necroposting) logic from forums do not apply at all. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Comment: I like that you added this comment almost exactly 8 years after the question was asked :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you looking at the ***age*** of the question?  Look at the *question* instead.  Look at what's improved before you get that queasy feeling.

The first version of it reads like rambling.  Lots and lots of senseless rambling.  Towards the end, we get the question:

> **My questions:**
>
> - Is there any shortcuts available for this ? (Don't tell me to use 'find and replace')
> - Is there any such hidden features available in Xcode ? (means features that are not listed in the Xcode menus)

There was a lot of noise in the beginning to get to the *actual* question:  how do they edit all variables in a scope via a keyboard shortcut?

The second portion of this would have made the question too broad, since it's not centered around a specific thing anymore (other hidden features is a rabbit hole lying in wait).

Now, the revision reads **better**.

> Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? (Please don’t tell me to use “Find and replace”.)

I'm summarizing briefly since I'd rather not paste the entire question here, but this is the nugget:  is there a keyboard shortcut for editing all variables in a scope?

This is a very, very good edit.  I'm not upset about this at all.  It makes an older, useful question a lot more clear and understandable.  It should be lauded.

While there may exist [an official guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) on the matter, I want you to bear in mind that the intent is to *improve* the content we have here.  If you feel like it's been improved, then let's work from there.  The only times you have to refer to the guideline is when there's been "improvement", but the improvements themselves have been borderline.

Comment: "It makes an older, useful question a lot more clear and understandable. It should be lauded." << that made it a lot clearer what to look for when reviewing edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I approved the edit in question, and it's worth putting in my two cents here.

There are guidelines to editing, and this applies to the edit review queue as well.

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing (emphasis mine):

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - *To fix grammar and spelling mistakes*
> - *To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)*
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

The suggested edit you've linked definitely covers bullets number one and two, namely "To fix grammar and spelling mistakes" and "To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)". As such, this is a good edit and I would approve it. (As you can see)